# Onload arquivo .txt

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, rolamento

Tarde galera.
Preciso carregar o conteúdo de um arquivo .txt para uma pagina WEB, sendo que preciso ter controle sobre o scroll, preciso manter ele sempre no final da pagina, e uma atualização constante.

Comment: Qual linguagem está  a utilizar?

Comment: html, e js. tenho uma aplicação e estou limitado somente a essas parâmetros, também tenho suporte a css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>      
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = pageScroll;
        var a = 1000;
        function pageScroll()
          {
            window.scrollBy(0,a);
            scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 1000); 
              a += 10;
              document.getElementById('relatorio').style.height = a +"px";
              var f = document.getElementById('relatorio');
              f.src = f.src;
              
          } 


      </script>

  </head>
    <body>
      <div>
        <iframe
          id="relatorio"
          src="input.txt"
          width="auto"          
          frameborder="0"
          scrolling="no"
          allow-scripts= "pageScroll;"
          style="
            position:
            relative;
            width: 440px;"
            target="_self">
                    
        </iframe>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```